# highchart Stacked-area - Grouping small series

Tags: highcharts, stacked-area-chart

Is there a way to group small series in a new 'Others' series?
I have a chart with some series that are very small, so their areas almost doesn't appears in the chart. So, what I want is to group those small series making a new serie a little bigger called 'Others'. 
I did it by grouping my small series before setting them to the chart, but I think it would be better if highchart do it by his own. This way, if we hide a serie clicking in its legend, the chart could recalculte and check if the 'Others' could be ungrouped.

For example:
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-stacked
Since Europe and Oceania series are the smallest areas in the chart, is it possible to set some property for Highchart group those 2 series in a new one, called 'Others'? And when we click on the legend to hide some serie, highchart dinamically recalculate to check if the 'Others' serie could be divided again the the 'real' series

Comment: No, HIghcharts does not have the ability to do this on its own. You could build the functions to group/ungroup, and attach them to the legendItemClick event. Creating/managing the legend entries might be complex.

Comment: yep, that's what I thought... I did it like you said.. thanks

Comment: Highcharts have grouping option, maybe it will help you with your problem. http://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/data-grouping
If you want to group multiple series into one bigger series, you have to do it on your own, but if you think this is good idea to have this functionality in Highcharts, you can ask for it on Highcharts uservoice. https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api